# Matching values from two vectors

Tags: r, vector

I have two separate vectors `HG` and `AG` which represent two different soccer scores. One of them is the amount of home goals while the other is the amount of away goals. I'd like to know if there is a way of counting how many times a result occurs and putting it into a table, e.g. if value is 1 from `HG` and 2 from `AG` then the result is 1-2.  Then I would like to find  out how many times this score occurs.

Answer (score 5):

```
vector<-paste(HG,AG,sep="-")
result<-data.frame(table(vector))
```